# Is it safe to merge account with facebook login?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a small webapp that allows users to create accounts with us. We're adding Facebook (and other OAuth providers) login. Assuming I have a user with email: test@example.com and then suddenly a user tries to login with Facebook and I see that Facebook's user's email is test@example.com, is it safe to assume that it's the same user and to allow login as if the user had provided their password and merge the accounts?

Comment: its rare, but people do share email accounts

Comment: How sensitive is the data in your web app? If it's a medical records app, probably not. If it's something like Instagram, probably fine. There are definitely edge cases like @Dagon mentions, so it's ultimately a judgement call for you.

Comment: I didn't think about the sharing accounts angle. I guess the safe thing to do is if I find a user already registered with that email id, but not linked to FB, to prompt for password?

Comment: and @ceejayoz for the record it's an app where they can buy physical goods (and have transactions on file). So security, balanced with user experience, is definitely important.